# Proof that $\sqrt[p]{n}$ is irrational if $n$ is not a perfect pth power

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

i'm using Courant's book for self study, i would like to know if my proof that $\sqrt[p]{n}$ is irrational if $n$ is not a perfect pth power. Also would appreciate if someone do know where i can look for the solutions.

---

If $n$ is not a perfect pth power i can express it in terms of $n^{pm + 1}$. Assuming that $\sqrt[p]{n^{pm+1}}$ is rational i would have:

$$
\sqrt[p]{n^{pm+1}} = \frac{k}{j} \\
n^{pm + 1} = \frac{k^p}{j^p} \\
n^{pm + 1}j^p = k^p \\
n^mn^{\frac{1}{p}}j = k \\
j^p = \frac{k^p}{n^{pm+1}} \\
j = \frac{k}{n^mn^{\frac{1}{p}}}
$$

Which is a contradiction because they do have a common factor.

Comment: It seems to me like circular logic! What you ended up with is just a rearrangement of  the first equality/assumption!

Comment: Your first step is confusing and wrong. You are thinking that you can write $n = s^{pm+1}$ for some integer $s$ if $n$ is not a $p$th power, but this is wrong. (Try $n=2$ and $p=3$.) I don't know that book, so I can't guess what technique you're supposed to try. Has he proved the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, perhaps?

Comment: @TedShifrin sorry about that, that's one of my first tries to proof something. He didn't yet proved the FTA.

Answer (score 0):

We will prove the contrapositive statement. Suppose that $\sqrt[p]{n}$ is rational i.e $~ \sqrt[p]{n}=\frac{a}{b}, ~ b \ne 0 $. Assume that $gcd(a,b)=1$, so $gcd(a^{p},b^{p})=1.$ Now, $n = \frac{a^{p}}{b^{p}}$, but $gcd(a^{p},b^{p})=1$ and $n$ is an integer implies that $b^{p}=1$. So, $n=a^{p}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let be

$$
a_0 x^n  +  \cdots a_n  = 0
$$
a polynomial equation where $a_i \in \mathbb Z$. Then if $x$ is a rational root of this equation it must be of the form $x=\frac{r}{s}$ where $r$ is a divisor of $a_n$ and $s$ a divisor of $a_0$. Now consider the equation $$x^p-n=0.$$ You would have that $r^p=n$ which is a contradiction .

Comment: This is the monic case of the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).